# Pandas dropna() not working (it definitely isn't the common reasons why!)

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

[image]

There are many NaNs that were somehow produced when transforming data:

[image]

So I try to drop them using:

```
df = df.dropna(how='all')
```

I still just get this (I know I'm only showing 3 columns, but all the columns are filled with NaNs)

[image]

I've tried assuming their string and using:

```
df = df[~df.isin(['NaN']).any(axis=1)]
```

This also didn't work. Any other thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you slice with a Boolean **DataFrame** the [logic used is `where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking). That is, where the mask is `True` it returns the value, where the mask is `False` it by default chooses `np.NaN`.

Thus, if you are slicing with `df.isna()` by definition you `NaN` **everything**. This is because where `df.isna()` is True it passes the value (`NaN`) and where the df was not null `where` passes `NaN`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': np.NaN, 'bar': np.NaN, 'baz': np.NaN, 'boo': 1}, index=['A'])
#   foo  bar  baz  boo
#A  NaN  NaN  NaN    1

df.isnull()
#    foo   bar   baz    boo
#A  True  True  True  False

df[df.isnull()]
#   foo  bar  baz  boo
#A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

df.where(df.isnull())
#   foo  bar  baz  boo
#A  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

So you don't have rows full of `NaN`, your mask just guarantees every cell becomes `NaN`. If you want to inspect rows that are `NaN` without modifying the values you can display rows with at least 1 `NaN`:

```
df[df.isnull().any(1)]
#   foo  bar  baz  boo
#A  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
```

Or to see the distribution of `NaN` across the rows take the value counts of the sum across rows. This shows we have 1 row with 3 null values.

```
df.isnull().sum(1).value_counts()
#3    1
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow...I had no idea. Thanks so much. I did wonder why the number of rows were the same. 
How come it works when a column is specified?:

data = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[np.NaN, 1,2], 'bar': [np.NaN,3,4], 'baz': [np.NaN,7,8], 'boo':[1,3,4]}, index=['A','B','C']).



data[data['foo'].isna()]. 

Sorry, I have no idea how to post code as a comment

Comment: @Jameson Since Series are 1D, when you slice with a Boolean Series (like in your comment) the only sensible alignment is along the row Index. So with a Series it just returns the entire row where the Boolean Series is True

Comment: Because a DataFrame has to be by definition 2D rectangular when you slice by a DataFrame, allowing for alignment across both axes (rows and columns) it needs to figure out what to do. Imagine your mask is [[True, True], [False, True]]. It can't return something with 2 cells in the first row and one in the second, because that's not rectangular. So it uses `where` under the hood to ensure the result is 2D, and fills with a default value.